# Postgresql: insert and update child tables based on the data inserted into parent table autometically

Tags: postgresql

I have a master table in which all types of email logs are present e.g- delivered, opened, clicked etc. Now I want to create child tables for separate events so that It should insert rows from master table automatically if it matches the event name and if it is not already there in child table, and this operation should be done after every insertion in master table. I tried a lot and read about partitioning but didn't get to the point answer, Please provide me a small example or link if possible, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't really have a way to do this out of the box using specific tools for the task at hand.  In my experience regarding partitioning the best way to do this is:

1. Create your master table with a `check noinherit` constraint that is set to false.  This means you cannot insert rows directly into the master table.  Name it something that is not what you query directly (this is optional but very helpful if using an ORM).
2. Set up your child tables with correct, non-overlapping check constraints.
3. Create a view which simply selects against your master table.  Create a trigger which inserts or updates the child rows ad returns *

However, partitioning impacts a lot of other things.  It may not be what you are looking for.  If all you want is to insert rows into other additional tables, just create a trigger for that.  That is what is there for.